# How can i add a link to a button?

Tags: html

I know its a noob + simple question but I actually cant find how to do:

```
<button onlick = takes you to a link>
```

I searched up a lot lol, but can you answer it straight up?

Comment: You can't (without JavaScript), and you shouldn't. Use the proper element for navigation, which is an anchor. Style it as you like.

Comment: The linked duplicate will show you how to redirect the user with JavaScript.  But I'd like to reiterate the comment above... A button which *only* redirects a user should be a link.

Comment: Wrap it around an anchor tag <a href='https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/'>
        <button class="GFG">
            Click Here
        </button>
    </a>

Comment: Here is the website for more info https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link/

Comment: @MegaMindTheCoder: Mixing buttons and links like that is just solving a problem by creating more problems.  It's also invalid HTML, according to the W3C validator.

Comment: @David oh okay sorry. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: @David the first time when I was only coding with html that's how I used to do it now I use react